The symmetry group of the hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ consists of orthogonal transformations
I am trying to prove that that the symmetry group of the $n$-dimensional hypercube $C_{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, defined as
$$\mathrm{Sym}(C_{n})=\{g\in\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{R})\colon g(C_{n})=C_{n}\}$$
is a subgroup of the orthogonal group $O(n)=\{g\in\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{R})\mid \langle u,v\rangle=\langle g(u),g(v)\rangle \ \text{for all} \ u,v\in\mathbb{R}^{n} \}$.
I managed to prove it via a rather involved way. First I proved the following results:

Every $g\in\mathrm{Sym}(C_{n})$ also fixes vertices of $C_{n}$, that is the
set of vectors $S:=\{-1,1\}^{n}$, i.e. $\mathrm{Sym}(S)=\mathrm{Sym}(C_{n})$.

Every $g\in\mathrm{Sym}(C_{n})$ fixes the facets of $C_{n}$. which are precisely the sets
$F_{i,\pm 1}:=\mathrm{conv}(S_{i,\pm 1})$, where $S_{i,\pm 1}=\{s\in S\colon s_{i}=\pm 1\}$.


Then, if $g\in\mathrm{Sym}(C_{n})$ and $i\in[n]$, we have that $g(S_{i,1})=S_{j_{i},\epsilon_{i}}$,
for some $j_{i}\in[n]$ and $\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}$. Notice also that if $e_{1},\dots,e_{n}$ is the
standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then
$$ e_{i}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{s\in S_{i,1}}s\in F_{i,1}$$
and so
$$ g(e_{i})=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{s\in S_{i,1}}g(s)=
        \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{s\in S_{j_{i},\epsilon_{i}}}s=\epsilon_{i}\cdot e_{j_{i}}
        \in F_{j_{i},\epsilon_{i}}. $$
We now finally prove that $g\in O(n)$, by proving that it maps the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to an orthogonal basis. Indeed, if we take $i\neq i'\in[n]$ such that
$$\langle g(e_{i}),g(e_{i'})\rangle=\epsilon_{i}\cdot\epsilon_{i'}\cdot 
\langle e_{j_{i}},e_{j_{i'}}\rangle\neq 0,$$
then $j:=j_{i}=j_{i'}$. Notice also that since $g$ is injective we must have that $\epsilon:=\epsilon_{i}=-\epsilon_{i'}$. But then,
$g(F_{i,1})=F_{j,\epsilon}$ and $g(F_{i',1})=F_{j,-\epsilon}$, which is a contradiction since
$$ F_{i,1}\cap F_{i',1}=\mathrm{conv}(\{s\in S\colon s_{i}=s_{i'}=1\})\neq\emptyset $$
and
$$ \emptyset\neq g(F_{i,1}\cap F_{i',1})= F_{j,\epsilon}\cap F_{j,-\epsilon}=\emptyset.$$
Therefore, $j_{i}\neq j_{i'}$ and so $\langle g(e_{i}),g(e_{i'})\rangle=0$. This proves that $g\in O(n)$.


My concern is that this, as you can see, is a rather involved proof. I think there is a much more general argument, which I don't see.
I would really like to show this also for an arbitrary regular polytopes or even better for an arbitrary polytope that contains the origin, if the latter is indeed true.

It is not true for an arbitrary polytope, e.g. consider a right triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 2)$, which has a linear symmetry permuting its legs which is not orthogonal.

@QiaochuYuan Oh, I see. Maybe if the origin is an internal point of the polytope?

I don't think that should matter, you can modify the previous example by moving the vertex at the origin to an eigenvector of the linear symmetry.
